# MOSS 2007 Custom application page working on IP but not on Intranet and Internet URL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, iis-6, moss2007-security

I have implemented a custom application page on MOSS 2007 site. I have put the VS folder in layouts and did all the necessary changes in web.config and gac. The custom application page is working smoothly using IP address

e.g.:`(http://)IP:portnumber/_layouts/Applicationfolder/page.aspx`.

But as soon as i try using the Intranet or internet url e.g.: /abc/_layouts/Applicationfolder/page.aspx or http://abc.orgname.com/_layouts/Applicationfolder/page.aspx. I get the below error. Please help me..

```
Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags)
```

I faced the above error after deploying and I followed below solution given in link:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/602705ce-08a3-41af-a6fe-b1472b048532

But now the Application page is working only on IP and throwing above error on Intranet and Internet URL.
I have also checked the Alternate access mapping. As it is production and the rest of the sites are working fine with both IP and URL.
I think it might be some configuration or ASP.net Authentication issue. I may be wrong. Just a guess.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you have anonymous access enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for the anonymous access enabled ?

Did u have alternate access mapping configured for this site ?

If no, then follow this link to configure it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814(office.12).aspx
'it is for the Moss 2007 but the concepts are same.